# Windows 10: How to deal with foldernames ending with space(s) that are allowed on Linux but cannot be used any further in Windows Explorer?

Tags: linux, windows-10, filesystems, exfat, files-folders

This is a follow up of [Windows 10 trouble with  as an allowed foldername ending on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627248/windows-10-trouble-with-space-as-an-allowed-foldername-ending-on-linux?noredirect=1#comment1173716_627248).

This happens when you paste a file into a folder that has a space ending, it simply doubles, and the previous files disappear and will only reappear after renaming the folder and re-opening.

[image]
[image]

For more details and screenshots see the link. **This is not a cross-post. Please answer only for the Windows side here.**

The problem was on an exfat SD-card, though I guess that it happens with NTFS as well. It is most probably more of a Windows file management problem, as I know that there are controls of file and folder renaming at run-time. For example, if you rename a folder just by changing to upper case, that change is not accepted on Windows. When you add a space ending, it is directly cleaned. But this is done directly at run-time. I do not know how to deal with this when it has already happened on Linux.

Although it has started as a Linux question, now the question on the Windows side opens up:

1. whether there is a chance to manage Windows 10 Windows Explorer in such a way that such Linux folders with space(s) at the end are accepted "as they are", so that you can paste files into them even if they are not in the usual Windows format without spaces.
2. or whether there is a way to generally remove such spaces in Windows, so that they are also removed when going back to Linux. (*Not sure if that was so good, though, since in some rare cases, such spaces might be used on purpose to make a difference between folder versions or could be a useful step while managing your folders.*)

Comment: I am too lazy to test it but I am almost 100% sure that using the win32 api directly will allow you to do this.  I am not sure of any utility that will.. sorry.. it falls into the category of "don't do that".. also `such spaces might be used on purpose to make a difference between folder versions` .. sure.. by an idiot trying to obfuscate his work.